# Why is Windows7 waking up after I put it to sleep?

Tags: windows-7, sleep

Just about every night I put my Windows 7 computer to sleep, and then I turn off the power to my bluetooth keyboard.  Almost always, the next morning my computer has woken up, keyboard still off.

I'm using a Microsoft Wireless Desktop 7000 keyboard (no mouse) and the associated USB adapter.  Everything is setup so my keyboard can wake up my PC.

Why is my Windows 7 computer waking up after I put it to sleep (without any keyboard input)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Make sure the settings for the network card look like this, as this is a none issue for most xp versions

Comment: awesome, I'll let you know if it works.. fwiw my pc isn't cabled, I run it on wireless, but the wired adapter is still on and had that setting ticked.

Comment: That'll be the problem 100% this has happened to many people before

Comment: good stuff, man I had this problem for a long time